# I cannot make the default PHP on MacOS be PHP 7.2. This causes issues with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, macos, version

I installed PHP 7.2 with

```
brew install php72
```

I did the steps of setting up composer for use with Laravel and installed Laravel according to this video:
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-6-from-scratch/episodes/3?autoplay=true
Then when I ran

```
laravel new freshproject
```

I got errors saying I needed PHP 7.2, even though I had installed it.
(I assume this is related to how typing "php -v" gave me PHP 7.1.)

Comment: What `which php` shows?

Comment: Please can you show the output of `brew services list`.